# Compounding distribution of a Gaussian Mixture

Tags: probability

I want to find an analytical expression (if it exists) for the compound density $f_Y(y)$ of a Gaussian distribution whose mean is distributed according to a Gaussian mixture. However, I'm not sure if my reasoning (as well as my notation) is correct.

Let the compound distribution be
$$
f_Y(y)=\int f_X(x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)\,dx,
$$
where $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\mathcal{N}(y;x,\sigma_y^2)$, $f_X(x)=\sum\limits_{i}\alpha_if_i(x)$ is a Gaussian mixture density with components $f_i(x)=\mathcal{N}(x;\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ and $\alpha_i$ are the mixture weights $\alpha_i \ge 0, \sum \alpha_i=1$.

By pushing the integral into the mixture some and substituting for the density expressions we get
$$
\begin{align}
f_Y(y)&=\int f_X(x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)\,dx \\
&=\sum\limits_{i}\alpha_i\int f_i(x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)\,dx \\
&=\sum\limits_{i}\alpha_i\int \mathcal{N}(x;\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)\mathcal{N}(y;x,\sigma_y^2)\,dx 
\\
&=\sum\limits_{i}\alpha_i\,\mathcal{N}(y;\mu_i,\sigma_i^2 + \sigma_y^2). \
\end{align}
$$
The last step results from the following considerations
$$
\begin{align}
X &= \mu + Z, \quad Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_x^2)\\
Y &=X+R, \quad R \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_y^2),
\end{align}
$$
then
$$
Y = \mu + Z + R, \quad Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2),
$$
if $Z$ and $R$ are independent.

### Simulation Update

I have now checked my results experimentally, as shown in the following figure. The lines indicate the analytic densities of $f_X$ and $f_Y$ (as derived above). The samples are created using ancestral sampling (i.e first sample from $f_X$, then $f_{Y|X}$) and seem to match the analytic densities.

[image]

### Proof Update

After reading my derivation the next day, I immediately felt that the steps did not convince me. So here is another attempt using convolutions and their connections to sum of Gaussian rvs.

From above:

$$
\begin{align}
f_Y(y)&=\int f_X(x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)\,dx \\
&=\sum\limits_{i}\alpha_i\int f_i(x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)\,dx \\
&=\sum\limits_{i}\alpha_i\int \mathcal{N}(x;\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)\mathcal{N}(y;x,\sigma_y^2)\,dx 
\\
&=\sum\limits_{i}\alpha_i\int \mathcal{N}(x;\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)\mathcal{N}(y-x;0,\sigma_y^2)\,dx
\end{align}
$$

The integral in the last step now takes the form of a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(y-x)\,dx.$$ Using the [facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) that

1. the sum of two independent random variables equals the convolution of their densities and
2. the sum of two independent Gaussian random variables is again Gaussian

we find the result of the convolution is $$\mathcal{N}(y;\mu_i,\sigma_i^2 + \sigma_y^2).$$

Comment: The result should be correct. The final result is a Gaussian mixture itself.