# Gaussian variable condition on another Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution

I want to find the distribution of one Gaussian distribution conditioned on another Gaussian.
Let's say I have the first Gaussian variable $x \sim \mathcal N(y, \sigma^2_1)$, which is conditioned on another Gaussian variable $y \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2_2)$. What is the exact distribution of variable $x$?

I saw another post similar to this. [Compounding distribution of a Gaussian Mixture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338946/compounding-distribution-of-a-gaussian-mixture). But I am not sure whether this could use convolution. More importantly, if it is that case, how is the convolution derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to find the unconditional distribution of $X$ is by noting that there are two independent standard normals $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$ such that
$$
X=Y+\sigma_1\varepsilon_1=\mu+\sigma_2\varepsilon_2+\sigma_1\varepsilon_1
$$
holds. This can be written as
$$\tag{1}
X=\mu+\sigma\varepsilon
$$
where $\varepsilon$ is a new standard normal and $\sigma=\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}$. Therefore $X\sim{\cal N}(\mu,\sigma^2)\,.$

A more complicated way is to write
$$
\mathbb P\{X\le z\}=\int_{-\infty}^z\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_1\sigma_2}\exp\Big(-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2\sigma_1^2}\Big)\exp\Big(-\frac{|y-\mu|^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\Big)\,dy\,dx
$$
The inner integral is the convolution of two normal PDFs and it is possible to show that this equals
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}}\exp\Big(-\frac{|x-\mu|^2}{2(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)}\Big)
$$
which is the PDF of (1).

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I could understand the reparametrization trick, but the part I am confused most about is how did you get $\sigma = \sqrt{\sigma_1^2+ \sigma_2^2}$ Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: This $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $\sigma_1\varepsilon_1+\sigma_2\varepsilon_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, independent of $y$.
Then, $x|y$ has the same distribution as $y+\sigma_1\epsilon$.
Since $\epsilon$ and $y$ are independent, $x$ is Gaussian, with variance $\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2$ and mean $\mu$.